# Saving lightbox data when a new lightbox open above Wix

Tags: javascript, caching, lightbox, velo

I'm losing the user's data when the user filled his details [image: into my lightbox] and then I open the registration lightbox

For example - user open the lightbox, filled his details but he is not registered so the user goes to the registration lightbox but when he finished his registration the previous lightbox is gone (automatically closed) with the user filled data

For solving this problem I tried to enable caching[image]
the lightbox working by the code

```
wixData.query("Projects").find().then( (results) => {
  $w('#repeater1').data = results.items;

  console.log("Number of projects:", results.length);
  renderProjects();
});


export function renderProjects () {
  console.log("renderProjects() was called");
  $w('#repeater1').forEachItem(($item, itemData, index) => {


    $item("#projectName").text = itemData.title;
    $item("#descriptionField").text = itemData.description.substring(0,50);
    $item("#categoryField").text = itemData.category;
```

Answer (score 1):

Corvid does enable you to have access to local browser storage using the [wix-storage API](https://www.wix.com/corvid/new-reference/wix-storage#top). You can use this to temporarily store and then restore their responses.